# XML points drawing with svg using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I am a total newbie in these techs and I need your help.
I need to draw via svg points saved in xml file. I need to use xsl for transformation. When i will open this xml with any general browser ie ie, mozilla, I want to draw these points as circles.

Their position is described with x and y  coordinates. I used 1000x1000px background canvas. Pls can you show me what is wrong in this script and how to make it running?
Thank you very much.

This is a sample of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="points.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>

<waypoints>
  <point>
    <X>20</X>
    <Y>20</Y>
  </point>
  <point>
    <X>50</X>
    <Y>50</Y>
  </point>
</waypoints>
```

and this is what I till now try to write in xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="no"
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"
media-type="image/svg" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="waypoints//point">
    <xsl:variable name="svg_cx" select="waypoints/point/X"/>
    <xsl:variable name="svg_cy" select="waypoints/point/Y"/>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1000" height="1000" >
      <circle cx={$svg_cx} cy={$svg_cy} r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output the root element outside of the `for-each` and use relative paths inside:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<xsl:output
method="xml"
indent="yes"
standalone="no"
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"
media-type="image/svg" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<svg width="1000" height="1000" >

<xsl:for-each select="waypoints//point">
  <circle cx="{X}" cy="{Y}" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</xsl:for-each>

</svg>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its running :)